# How do you dynamically get subclasses in an inheritance hierarchy when there are derived classes mainly for extending state not for behaviour?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, instanceof

I am trying to consume my tumblr data by using [Jumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr) which is a Tumblr API wrapper client for Java.

I have studied the source code and have seen that since Json response is dynamic, there is a Post POJO and derived POJOs like TextPost, QuotePost, PhotoPost etc. to deserialize to pojos. It handles consuming in a generic way by using Gson with a custom deserializer which uses reflection. In this way, for example it deserializes a Json response to a TextPost and assigns it to Post object.

So in order to get subclass' field, I need to downcast Post object after `instanceof` checks like this:

```java
List<Post> posts =  blog.draftPosts();
Post post = posts.get(0); //gets a TextPost
if(post instanceof TextPost) {
    System.out.println("title: " + ((TextPost) post).getTitle());
    System.out.println("body: " + ((TextPost) post).getBody()); 
}
else if(post instanceof QuotePost) {
    //...
}
else if...
```

I am not sure this is the best way. So I am searching for more elegant or a best way or a correct way from the perspective of object-oriented programming concepts like polymorphism or others.

What is the right approach to get subclass or access to it from a superclass?

How do you evaluate API's object oriented design which uses inheritance by extending specific classes which contain extra state? Is it a reasonable approach and what are the other ways from the perspective of the client which will be handling response? Since it is not behavior inheritance, is it right to use inheritance to only inherit state?

From the API source:

```java
public class Post {
    protected PostType type;
    private Long id;
    private String author;
    private String reblog_key;
    private String blog_name;
    //more state and getters/setters
}

public class TextPost extends Post {
    //extra fields
    private String title;
    private String body;

    //getters/setters
}


public List<Post> getPosts() {
    Gson gson = gsonParser();
    JsonObject object = (JsonObject) response;
    List<Post> l = gson.fromJson(object.get("posts"), new 
                        TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType());
    ...
}

private Gson gsonParser() {
        return new GsonBuilder().
            registerTypeAdapter(Post.class, new PostDeserializer()).
            create();
    }

public class PostDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jobject = je.getAsJsonObject();
        String typeName = jobject.get("type").getAsString();
        String className = typeName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + typeName.substring(1) + "Post";
        try {
            Class<?> clz = Class.forName("com.tumblr.jumblr.types." + className);
            return jdc.deserialize(je, clz);
....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: There is no "right" approach, but rather elegant and inelegant ones. Common patterns to handle this type of problem are one of the following:

1. Have a different class decide by the subclass of your object how to process (as you did in your example).
2. Move the responsibility to process the subclasses state into the subclasses via a (abstract) method of the abstract base class which every subclass must implement in their own way.
3. Move the responsibility to process the subclasses state into a visitor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) which gets "visited" by each subclass and who implements the behaviour depending on the type of the calling object.